# My routes.rb file doesn't redirect me to /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have created a NEW rails application using

rails new rail_app

So if I want to see my development site I need to do the following

http://localhost:3000/Site/index

I want to reroute all requests to http://localhost:3000

The book I'm using to learn from is an older version of rails and it tells me to uncomment

map.connect '', :controller => 'site', :action => 'index'

but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to direct a controller action to root using the *root* command. See this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Index.html from public folder.

Create a new controller say home using

```
rails g controller home
```

Add a index.html to app/views/home.

Open routes.rb

uncomment `root :to => "welcome#index"`

rewrite it as `root :to => "home#index"`

Now if you type http://localhost:3000 , you will be redirected to your index page.

You can also go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for advanced routing concepts.